# google search page inside of the flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

How to include google search page inside of my flex web application without using iframe. Any alternative way for solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://drumbeatinsight.com/htmlcomponent

Runs a html browser inside a Flex application.

Works really well!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There are obvious security concerns about displaying full HTML inside the Flash Player. Adobe stick to the "It's too big, it would bloat the player" line though.

Comment: what are the security concerns? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: Man in the middle attacks mainly. It looks like the web page you expected to see, but really it's running in a Flash Player, stealing your goodies.